# How do I set IntelliJ to place xml tags on separate lines when formatting xml files?

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, formatting

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 12.  I've used the context menu to import some pom.xml maven dependencies.  However, when I view the POM file, the dependencies are not formatted nicely--they are in a single line.   When I reformat the pom file (Ctrl-Alt-L) the formatting is still not fixed.

I tried looking at Project Settings > code style > XML, but I couldn't see an obvious setting that would fix this.  I fiddled with "keep line breaks" and "wrap text" settings, but to no avail.

I have noticed that other XML files have the same issue--if I join them, formatting won't break them apart.

How can I get IntelliJ to intelligently break xml across multiple lines, with proper indentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uncheck the option "keep white spaces" in the settings.

In IDEA 12, File > Settings > Code Style (left menu panel) > XML (left menu panel) > Other (tab) > Keep White Spaces (checkbox)